# Need to subclass spring-ldap transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-ldap

We have a custom transaction manager that does some audit work as each transaction begins.  But we are retrofitting this into a spring-ldap app, and it's declared like this:

```
<ldap:transaction-manager id="ldapTransactionManager" session-factory-ref="sessionFactory" >
   <ldap:default-renaming-strategy />
</ldap:transaction-manager>
```

We want to hook into the doBegin of that class which appears to be ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager.  But there's no attribute of ldap:transaction-manager> that I see which would allows me to subclass and supply my own.  Or is there some listener I can plug into?  I just need to run a little code each doBegin of the transaction.

Comment: Perhaps see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/transaction/compensating/manager/ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager.html). Inherit and register with Spring (by id and hook into the config - in your code), if it will fit the purpose?

Comment: @h.alex - That is the class I want to subclass.  But how to get spring-ldap to use my subclass instead of that one, is the question.  That is the class that <ldap:transaction-manager> uses by default. I just don't see how to override it.